# Работа с большими объёмами данных java

Tags: java, хранение-данных, передача-данных, работа-с-текстом

Сейчас мне необходимо хранить в словаре(`HashMap`) неограниченное кол-во строк вида **"key=value"**.
Это занимает огромное кол-во памяти и я хотел бы узнать, какие ещё могут быть решения этой проблемы с памятью?

Желательно вообще не хранить в памяти. Записать, например, все строки в файл и из него с ними работать. Но тут есть две проблемы.
В словарь я часто как добавляю, так и удаляю записи. Со словарём эти операции достаточно просты. 
А в файле для добавления придётся снова открывать файл и записывать в него, а при удалении вообще переписывать файл полностью, не добавляя в него ту строку, которую хочу удалить.

Буду очень благодарен, если кто-то предложит способ хранения данных лучше или поправит меня по поводу методов взаимодействия с данными в файле.

Comment: Рассматривали вариант хранить данные в базе данных, и точечно изменять их?)

Comment: Решение зависит от конкретной задачи, серебряной пули на все случаи жизни не существует

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте [mapdb](http://www.mapdb.org/). Работает примерно так:

```
DB db = DBMaker.fileDB("myfile.db").make();
String key="myKey";
HTreeMap myMap = db.hashMap("myMap").createOrOpen();
myMap.put(myKey, "Hello World");
```

`HTreeMap` - это собственно говоря и есть искомая коллекция расширяющая стандартный класс `HashMap`, но делающая это на основе дискового образа (по сути БД).

P.S. @andreymal при известной натяжке это и есть *серебряная пуля* :)

Answer (score 0):

Используйте sqlite базу данных, получите возможность хранить сколько угодно слов и неплохо оптимизировать поиск

Comment: “Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению.”